# When installing a Generic Host as a service in NServiceBus, how do I provide valid credentials?

Tags: nservicebus, topshelf

Imagine I create a .bat file in the following directory:

\trunk\Samples\PubSub\

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO installing Subscriber 1
Subscriber1\bin\Debug\NServiceBus.Host.exe /install
pause
ECHO installing Subscriber 2
Subscriber2\bin\Debug\NServiceBus.Host.exe  /install
pause
ECHO starting Subscriber services
net start Subscriber1.EndPointConfig_v1.0.0.0
net start Subscriber2.EndPointConfig_v1.0.0.0
pause
```

I get prompted for a username and password, but using my own credentials I get an exception as follows:

> An exception occurred during the Install phase.
>   System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The account name is invalid or does not ex
>   ist, or the password is invalid for the account name specified

1. what credentials can I pass to get this to work?
2. can I configure credentials as command line arguments to [NServiceBus.Host.exe](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/nservicebus/index.php?title=Generic_Host) or run as 'Local System Account'?

**Note:**

My research so far suggests that (2) may be something that [TopShelf](http://code.google.com/p/topshelf) supports via it's IInstallationConfiguration

I'm doing this on a Vista machine with MSMQ installed already.

The PubSub sample runs as expected if I just run the subscriber instances as console apps (i.e. like this):

```
@ECHO OFF
ECHO starting Subscriber 1
Subscriber1\bin\Debug\NServiceBus.Host.exe NServiceBus.Integration
pause
```

Comment: For anyone who wants to reproduce this I should add that I've been adapting the PubSub sample solution by running NServiceBus.Host.exe with the /install argument to cause it to be installed as a Windows Service instead of running as a Console app.

As described in the NSB wiki, NServiceBus.Host.exe scans its current directory for any dlls with a suitable configuration that it can use to configure itself. The sample does this via the EndpointConfig class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> *(2.) can I configure credentials as command line arguments to NServiceBus.Host.exe or run as 'Local System Account'?*

After digging around in TopShelf and NSB source code I discovered that this is pretty simple:

For anyone who's interested - this is something the TopShelf implements with [IRunnerConfigurator](http://code.google.com/p/topshelf/source/browse/trunk/src/Topshelf/Configuration/IRunnerConfigurator.cs).RunAsLocalSystem. NServiceBus calls this method if you add the marker interface ISpecify.ToRunAsLocalSystem

So the answer is to add ISpecify.ToRunAsLocalSystem to the list of interfaces implemented by the EndpointConfig class.

I didn't find an answer to:

> *(1.) what credentials can I pass to get this to work?*

But now I don't really need one now as I'm happy enough to run the services as Local System.

Comment: Matt Burton has since added the following change to trunk:

 - made RunAsLocalSystem the default installation for the host, unless overridden by /username & /password command line arguments
 
- removed ISpecify.ToRunAsLocalSystem

http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=6473&buildTypeId=bt60&tab=buildChangesDiv

Comment: I have a similar problem: I want to run as LocalSystem, but if I omit the username/password, the installer pops up a username/password dialog. Not sure if this is something new or not. Any idea what I can do about this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is relevant but Matt Burton added the following commit recently:

- [added command line credential support to host](http://teamcity.codebetter.com/viewLog.html?buildId=6366&buildTypeId=bt60&tab=buildChangesDiv)

I've yet to try it but my question (1) may now be irrelevant.