# How can I enable logging for an NServiceBus Generic Host

Tags: log4net, nservicebus, topshelf

I didn't want to make the title too long but this question specifically refers to running an NServiceBus Generic Host as a Windows Service (thanks to TopShelf) configured to run as Local System (on a Vista machine)

In [a previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1487800/when-installing-a-generic-host-as-a-service-in-nservicebus-how-do-i-provide-vali) I explain why I decided to adapt the PubSub sample to run as a Windows Service so that I can easily stop and start the service to fully prove to myself that NServiceBus was doing what it was supposed to do.

For some reason I can't get Log4Net to log anything to disk, so this could well just be a Log4Net (newbie) configuration problem?

Below is my brute-force attempt to get some sort of tracing going - all I'm getting so far is files writen as follows:

> C:\logs\<-GUID->log4net.log

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="MsmqTransportConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.MsmqTransportConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <section name="UnicastBusConfig" type="NServiceBus.Config.UnicastBusConfig, NServiceBus.Core" />
    <sectionGroup name="common">
      <section name="logging" type="Common.Logging.ConfigurationSectionHandler, NServiceBus.Core"/>
    </sectionGroup>
    <section name="log4net" type="log4net.Config.Log4NetConfigurationSectionHandler,log4net"/>
  </configSections>

  <!-- in order to configure remote endpoints use the format: "queue@machine" 
       input queue must be on the same machine as the process feeding off of it.
       error queue can (and often should) be on a different machine.
  -->

  <MsmqTransportConfig
    InputQueue="worker2"
    ErrorQueue="error"
    NumberOfWorkerThreads="1"
    MaxRetries="5"
  />

  <UnicastBusConfig>
    <MessageEndpointMappings>
      <add Messages="Messages" Endpoint="messagebus" />
    </MessageEndpointMappings>
  </UnicastBusConfig>

  <common>
    <logging>
      <factoryAdapter type="Common.Logging.Log4Net.Log4NetLoggerFactoryAdapter, NServiceBus.Core">
        <arg key="configType" value="INLINE"/>
      </factoryAdapter>
    </logging>
  </common>

  <log4net debug="true">
    <appender name="RollingLogFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender,log4net">
      <param name="File" value="c:\logs\Subscriber2.log" />
      <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
      <rollingStyle value="Size" />
      <maxSizeRollBackups value="2" />
      <maximumFileSize value="100KB" />
      <staticLogFileName value="true" />
      <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd" />
      <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionpattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.appender.eventlogappender">
      <applicationname value="Subscriber2.EndPointConfig_v1.0.0.0" />
      <layout type="log4net.layout.patternlayout">
        <conversionpattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="TraceAppender" type="log4net.Appender.TraceAppender">
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
      </layout>
    </appender>


    <root>
      <level value="ALL" />
      <appender-ref ref="RollingLogFileAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="EventLogAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
      <appender-ref ref="TraceAppender" />
    </root>

  </log4net>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true">
      <listeners>
        <add
          name="textWriterTraceListener"
          type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\logs\log4net.log" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>
  </system.diagnostics>

</configuration>
```

Comment: The user account under which the service is running, does it have the proper permissions to write to c:\logs ?

Comment: The windows service is running as 'Local System'. As described in the other question I conuldn't find a way to install it to run as my own user account.

Comment: UPDATE: The correct solution was that  I had to add the marker interface IWantCustomLogging to my EndpointConfig class. Now I'm getting WAY TOO MUCH logging. But I'll leave the above config as an example of how to get the maximum logging and tracing...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NSB will not pick up log settings from config files as default. To do this implement IConfigureLogging in your endpoint config class.

More info here:

http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/nservicebus/message/3655

Hope this helps!

/Andreas

Comment: Whoa Andreas, thanks a million! This was spot on. I had to add the marker interface IWantCustomLogging - so obvious once you see it. Maybe I should have tried all the samples as is before trying to adapt one of them ;-)

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if your other two appenders are throwing exceptions while trying to log. I suspect the `%property{NDC}` in your patterns - remove them from the pattern and try again.

If your pattern contains %property{X} then you need to set a property with key "X" using code such as

```
ABC.Properties["X"] = /* some value */
```

where ABC is either a `LoggingEvent` instance or `ThreadContext` or `GlobalContext`.

I don't know if you've set properties with key "NDC", but I suspect not...

Comment: Thanks Vinay. I have removed these and fixed another error in the naming of the rolling file appender but I am still not getting any logging. I am debugging the apps in Visual Studio and it's stepping over the Logger.Info() lines OK. Very strange...